# How do I print table made from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json

My code is working fine but I can't print table that I made from JSON values. Any suggestions??

```
var resData = {"key1":"value","key2":"value"};

var table = $('<html/>').append('<thead><tr><th>Filter</th><th>Values</th></tr></thead>').appendTo('body'),
    tbody = table.append('<tbody/>');
$.each(resData, function(key, value){
    tbody.append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>');
});
console.log(table);
```

Comment: is there anything you getting on console?

Comment: where is `<table>..</table>` tag ?

Comment: you seem to have a typo, <html/> should probably be <html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can make like this.

```js
var resData = {"key1":"value","key2":"value"};

var table_str = '<table><thead><tr><th>Filter</th><th>Values</th></tr></thead>';
    table_str += '<tbody>';
$.each(resData, function(key, value){
    table_str +='<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>';
});
$("#content").html(table_str);
console.log(table_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first create complete table html in `var table` and then append table to body

Answer (score 0):

You can add a varible and concatinate it with value and then append to html

```
var resData = {"key1":"value","key2":"value"};

var table='<table><thead><tr><th>Filter</th><th>Values</th></tr></thead><tbody><tbody/>';
$.each(resData, function(key, value){
    table+='<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>';
});
table+='</table>';
$('<html/>').append(table);
console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the jQuery object directly to the console. I presume you need the html content of the table. You need to use `console.log(table.html())`. See the [html() docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in JavaScript:**

```js
var resData = {"key1":"value","key2":"value"};

var table = '<table><thead><tr><th>Filter</th><th>Values</th></tr></thead>';
table += '<tbody>';
for (var i in resData) {
    table += '<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+resData[i]+'</td></tr>';
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
```

```css
table,th,td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="table">
</div>
```